# Getting different projection results from same query using mongo and mongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am having a mongodb database from which I am trying to project some data. When I am using the following query in the mongo command line -

```
db.gholson.find({}, { "_id": 1 }).skip(85).limit(2).pretty();
```

I am getting the following output:-

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5abbde863f10ebda405b91f0"),
    "_id": ObjectId("5abbde863f10ebda405b91f1")
}
```

which is the desired output, but when I set up an express server and use the following query with MongoClient, I am getting all the fields instead of just the `ids`.

```
db.collection('gholson').find( {}, { "_id": 1 }).skip(85).limit(2).toArray(( err, result ) => {
        if( err ) throw err;
        console.log( result );
        callback();
    });
```

The above query returns all the key-value pairs instead of just id. I am unable to figure out, why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 3.0 of the driver the second argument of the `find` function represents `options`, not the projection. Try the following:

```
db.collection("gholson").find({}, { "projection": { "_id": 1 } })
```

or

```
db.collection("gholson").find({}).project({ "_id": 1 })
```